# How to add/remove input fields dynamically by a button in shiny

Tags: r, input, shiny, dynamic, shinyjs

I've been trying to find a solution how to add and remove input fields with a button in shiny. I don't have a source code since I haven't made that much progress, but this jQuery example (http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/) gives a good idea on what I'm trying to accomplish. Is this possible in shiny or should I use shinyjs to do this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT:** I read the jQuery example a bit more, and added a code snippet doing what I think you were looking for.

I don't know jQuery, so I couldn't make much out of the example link. I took a guess on what you wanted, but I think the key idea is the use of `renderUI` and `uiOutput` even if my suggestion here misses the point.

#### To toggle a ui element:

If you specifically don't want to use `shinyjs`, you could do something like this:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  actionButton("btn", "Toggle Textbox"),

  textOutput("btn_val"),
  uiOutput("textbox_ui")

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$btn_val <- renderPrint(print(input$btn))

  textboxToggle <- reactive({

    if (input$btn %% 2 == 1) {
      textInput("textin", "Write something:", value = "Hello World!")
    }

  })

  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxToggle() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### To add and remove elements:

After reading a bit of the jQuery example, I think this is similar to what you were looking for:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

      actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
      actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
      textOutput("counter")

    ),

  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })

  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))

  textboxes <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                  label = paste0("Textbox", i), value = "Hello World!")
      })
    }

  })

  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem with this approach is that each time you press the add or remove button, all of the input boxes get re-rendered. This means that any input you might have had on them disappears.

I think you could get around that by also saving the current input values of the input boxes into a `reactiveValues` object, and setting the values from the object as the starting values of the re-rendered input boxes by using the `value` option in `textInput`. I'll leave the implementation of that for now, though.

Comment: Can you kinld have a look at this query please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867997/dynamic-form-in-rshiny

Answer (score 6):

Thank you @Mikko Marttila for your answer. I was able to use it for my purpose. Also, referring to the issue of all input boxes getting re-rendered here I found a solution worked from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41061114/8436647). You can save all user inputs using `reactiveValuesToList()`, then call the reactive list accordingly to set every value to the corresponding user's input in the `lapply()` statement.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
    textOutput("counter")

  ),

  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  # Track all user inputs
  AllInputs <- reactive({
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })

  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))

  textboxes <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      isolate({
        lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
          textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                    label = paste0("Textbox", i), 
                    value = AllInputs()[[paste0("textin", i)]])
        })
      })
    }

  })

  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT**: I wrapped the `lapply()` statement in `isolate()` because it gets annoying when boxes are being re-rendered as you're trying to type in the field

Answer (score 2):

Instead of re-rendering the entire list of inputs, try the following

I keep track of all the `ids` that are created, I remove the last one created, and I reuse the `ids` of the deleted ones.
I start with an initial box (there is no real need for that, but I guess in a real work scenario you would expect at least 1 textBox to appear and increase thereafter). It is straightforward to start without the initial box.

Also, I keep track of the values of the `textInput` boxes that are currently active, in a reactive List. You would definitely need this

Lastly, I think for the two `reactiveValues` I have [`inserted` and `counter`], one of them is possibly redundant, but hey...

Hope it helps!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("insertBtn", "Insert"),
  actionButton("deleteBtn", "Delete"),
  h4("My boxes"),
  # Initial box here to start with. Not needed but it is nice to have one :)
  div(id = "box-1", textInput(inputId =  "box-1", label = "box-1")),
  div(id = "placeholder"),
  h4('Box contents'),
  verbatimTextOutput("my_inputs")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  ## keep track of elements inserted and a counter of the elements
  rv <- reactiveValues(
    inserted = c("box-1"),
    counter = 1
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$insertBtn, {
    
    rv$counter <- rv$counter+1
    serial <- rv$counter
    id <- paste0('box-', serial)
    rv$inserted <- c(rv$inserted, id)
    
    insertUI(
  
      selector = '#placeholder',      
      ## wrap element in a div with id for ease of removal
      ui = div(id = id,
               textInput(inputId =  id, label = paste0("box-", serial))
      )
    )
      
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteBtn, { 
    req(rv$counter>0) 
    # removes the last one 
    id_to_remove <- rv$inserted[length(rv$inserted)]
    
    removeUI(
      ## pass it in as JQuery selector
      selector = paste0('#', id_to_remove)
    )
    
    rv$inserted <- rv$inserted[-length(rv$inserted)]
    
    rv$counter <- rv$counter - 1
    
  })
  
  my_inputs <- reactive({
    
    req(rv$inserted) # need to have some inputs
    
    l <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
    
    # regex of the union of all inputs. Note the starting input box-1
    ids_regex <- paste(c("box-1", rv$inserted), collapse = "|")
    
    l[grepl(ids_regex, names(l))]
    
  })
  
  output$my_inputs <- renderPrint({
    
    my_inputs()
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Many thanks to

[this post](https://gallery.shinyapps.io/111-insert-ui/?_ga=2.49709926.1540773939.1656948188-152746694.1627292450)
[and this](https://mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)
and these SO posts [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454185/how-to-add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-by-a-button-in-shiny?noredirect=1&lq=1), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485186/r-shiny-how-to-create-an-add-field-button)