# Add/remove input fields dynamically by a button in shiny AND keep values

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

my question is a followup question on the following discussion:

[How to add/remove input fields dynamically by a button in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454185/how-to-add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-by-a-button-in-shiny)

I want a be able to add/remove dynamically input with action button on shiny app,  but also when I add a new input I want the values of the input fields to remain instead of change as it is now. Can you help me with this?

For example if I change the first box and add another text input via the button, the value of the first box has been reset with the default one.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

      actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
      actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
      textOutput("counter")

    ),

  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })

  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))

  textboxes <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                  label = paste0("Textbox", i), value = "Hello World!")
      })
    }

  })

  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 13):

There might be better solution but this also does the work:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
    textOutput("counter")
    
  ),
  
  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))
  
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
  
  #Track the number of input boxes previously
  prevcount <-reactiveValues(n = 0)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
        counter$n <- counter$n + 1
        prevcount$n <- counter$n - 1})
  
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) {
      counter$n <- counter$n - 1 
      prevcount$n <- counter$n + 1
    }
     
  })
  
  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))
  
  textboxes <- reactive({
    
    n <- counter$n
    
    if (n > 0) {
      # If the no. of textboxes previously where more than zero, then 
      #save the text inputs in those text boxes 
      if(prevcount$n > 0){
        
         vals = c()
        if(prevcount$n > n){
          lesscnt <- n
          isInc <- FALSE
        }else{
          lesscnt <- prevcount$n
          isInc <- TRUE
        }
        for(i in 1:lesscnt){
          inpid = paste0("textin",i)
         vals[i] = input[[inpid]] 
        }
        if(isInc){
          vals <- c(vals, "New text box")
        }
        
        lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
          textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                    label = paste0("Textbox", i), value = vals[i])
        })
        
      }else{
        lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
          textInput(inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                    label = paste0("Textbox", i), value = "New text box")
        }) 
      }
      
    }
    
  })
  
  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: A problem I'm having with this is that if my work flow is add Text box 1, type in text box 1, add text box 2, type in textbox 2, modify text in Text box 1, then the text in Text box 2 goes back to the default text.