# textInput not generating reactively in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Using help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233242/add-remove-input-fields-dynamically-by-a-button-in-shiny-and-keep-values), I'm trying to make a shiny app that looks like:

[image]
You can add more such `selectInput` and `textInput` using the `Add Operation` button (and delete them using `Remove Operation` button). My code goes as:

```
library(shiny)

mylist <- c('boxPlot','logNorm','pca')
params <- list()
params[[1]] <- list('columns')
params[[2]] <- c()
params[[3]] <- c('column','nComp')

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("add_btn", "Add Operation"),
        actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Operation")
    ),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
    # Track the number of input boxes to render
    counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)
    #Track the number of input boxes previously
    prevcount <-reactiveValues(n = 0)

    observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
        counter$n <- counter$n + 1
        prevcount$n <- counter$n - 1
    })

    observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
        if (counter$n > 0) {
            counter$n <- counter$n - 1 
            prevcount$n <- counter$n + 1
        }
    })

    textboxes <- reactive({
        n <- counter$n
        vals = c()
        indexOp = c()
        if (n > 0) {
            # If the no. of textboxes previously where more than zero, then 
            #save the text inputs in those text boxes 
            if(prevcount$n > 0){
                paramsVal <- list()
                if(prevcount$n > n){
                    lesscnt <- n
                    isInc <- FALSE
                }
                else{
                    lesscnt <- prevcount$n
                    isInc <- TRUE
                }
                for(i in 1:lesscnt){
                    inpid = paste0("textin",i)
                    vals[i] = input[[inpid]] 
                    for(j in 1:length(mylist)){
                        # if(strcmp(vals[i],mylist[j])){
                        if(vals[i]==mylist[j]){
                            indexOp[i] = j
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(isInc){
                    vals <- c(vals, mylist[1])
                    indexOp <- c(indexOp,1)
                }
                lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
                    tagList(
                        selectInput(
                            inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                            label = h3("Select operation"),
                            choices = mylist,
                            selected = vals[i]
                        ),
                        lapply(seq_len(length(params[[indexOp[i]]])), function(j) {
                            textInput(inputId = paste0("params",i,"_",j),label = params[[indexOp[i]]][j],value = "Parameter")
                        })
                    )                    
                })
            }
            else{    
                indexOp[1] = 1      
                lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
                    tagList(
                        selectInput(
                            inputId = paste0("textin", i),
                            label = h3("Select operation"),
                            choices = mylist,
                            selected = mylist[1]
                        ),
                        lapply(seq_len(length(params[[indexOp[i]]])), function(j) {
                            textInput(inputId = paste0("params",i,"_",j),label = params[[indexOp[i]]][j],value = "Parameter")
                        })
                    )
                })                
            }
        }
    })
    output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`mylist` is the list of operations the user can choose from. `params[[i]]` contains the arguments that the i-th function in `mylist` would take. `indexOp` just helps me retrieve the arguments based on the user input. Would be more than happy to explain the code even more if needed, please let me know as a comment if that's the case.

**The issue**

What I expect from it is that:

1. I click on add operation and get new fields for select and texts (function and argument).
2. Default function should be boxPlot, and default textInput must be for `columns`.
3. When I change the function from say boxPlot to pca, I should get 2 textInputs.

1 and 2 are happening as expected. But in 3, the textInput is not changed directly. It changes only after I add another operation after that. That is, if a operation is last, its textInputs don't change instantly but I have to add another operation to do so, but if it is not the last, they change instantly.

I want it work like the latter case, i.e., they change instantly irrespective of whether the operation is last or not. How can I do that? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

and welcome in the wonderful and all-powerful world of Shiny ;)

I do not like giving a fully-written answer. But I recently did something similar. So here are some tips:
 * I would recommend you to cut your code into pieces. I recently had some issues with a large Shiny module and cutting it into pieces (and writing abstract modules using (this)[https://www.r-bloggers.com/the-shiny-module-design-pattern/]) really helped.
 * Also, check out for these functions: `do.call()`, `switch()` for different cases, `formals()` to check for a function argument (helpful to write the rest).

I might have better written this as a comment (let me know, I am not perfectly used to SO yet), but giving good practices seem to be more important than giving all-made answers.

Enjoy and let me know if I well understood your issue.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you understood my question. I don't want to call the function or anything like that. I am given a list that does contain some function, but I'm not calling any of those. I just want to map those functions to their arguments and let the user provide their value in a `textInput`. The issue I'm facing, as I wrote, is that the change in textInput doesn't happen instantly, it requires me to add another operation below it before the changes can be displayed

Comment: Ok, I didn't get it at first. But I think I am still right ;)   
Indeed, I also tried something similar, and calling directly textInput didn't work, nor did it to write all in a single chunck.  
Prefer to have a function using `lapply()` and `do.call(textInput, ...)` in a module. I ensure you that following this will ease your task and the legibility of your work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll keep that it mind. For my case btw, I used `click(id)` to programatically trigger the add and remove operation buttons, and it did it. Not a proper solution, kind of just a work around :)