# shiny dynamically add input fields and data without getting re-rendered

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to dynamically add new variables to my shiny app which is working but if I start editing one, the values (text and numeric) reset each time I then add an additional variable. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468913/4083743) works without needing a for loop using `reactiveValuesToList()` but when I apply it to my code, it doesn't work. Here is my working example:

```
library(shiny)
dist <- c("Normal", "Gamma")
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
    textOutput("counter")

  ),

  mainPanel(uiOutput("textbox_ui"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  # Track all user inputs
  AllInputs <- reactive({
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {counter$n <- counter$n + 1})
  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) counter$n <- counter$n - 1
  })

  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))

  textboxes <- reactive({

    n <- counter$n

    if (n > 0) {
      isolate({
        lapply(seq_len(n), function(i) {
        fluidRow(
          selectInput(inputId = paste0("news", i),
                      label = paste0("Variable ", i),
                      choices = dist),

          conditionalPanel(
            condition = sprintf("input.%s=='Normal'", paste0("news", i)),
            textInput("txt", "Text input:", paste0("var", i)),  
            column(width = 3, numericInput('normal_mean', 'Mean', value = '0')), column(width = 3, numericInput('normal_sd', 'Standard deviation', value = '1'))),

          conditionalPanel(
            condition =  sprintf("input.%s=='Gamma'", paste0("news", i)),
            textInput("txt", "Text input:", paste0("var", i)),
            column(width = 3, numericInput('gamma_shape', 'Shape', value = '0')), column(width = 3, numericInput('gamma_scale', 'Scale', value = '1')))
        )
        })
      })
    }

  })

  output$textbox_ui <- renderUI({ textboxes() })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now if I try and add `AllInputs()[[]]` to `textInput` it doesn't keep the text in the `conditionalPanel` call:

```
conditionalPanel(
            condition = sprintf("input.%s=='Normal'", paste0("news", i)),
            textInput("txt", "Text input:", AllInputs()[[paste0("var", i)]]),  
            column(width = 3, numericInput('normal_mean', 'Mean', value = '0')), column(width = 3, numericInput('normal_sd', 'Standard deviation', value = '1')))
```

I'm also not sure how to include `AllInputs()[[]]` to the numeric values so that they dont change.

I think the problem is because of my `condition` line within `conditionalPanel` but can't figure it out, any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html) and `insertUI` / `removeUI`. Clicking on the buttons will not reset your changes on the inputs you already called. Here, you just have inputs so you only need to call the function `add_box` I created, but if you want to add outputs in the module, then you will need to use the function `callModule` in `observeEvent`. This is explained in the article I refer to.

This is not the method you suggested but it works.

```
library(shiny)

dist <- c("Normal", "Gamma")

add_box <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tags$div(id = paste0("new_box", id),
           selectInput(inputId = ns("news"),
                       label = paste0("Variable ", id),
                       choices = dist),

           conditionalPanel(
             condition = "input.news=='Normal'",
             ns = ns,
             textInput(ns("txt"), "Text input:", paste0("var", id)),  
             column(width = 3, numericInput(ns('normal_mean'), 'Mean', value = '0')), 
             column(width = 3, numericInput(ns('normal_sd'), 'Standard deviation', value = '1'))),

           conditionalPanel(
             condition =  "input.news=='Gamma'",
             ns = ns,
             textInput(ns("txt"), "Text input:", paste0("var", id)),
             column(width = 3, numericInput(ns('gamma_shape'), 'Shape', value = '0')), 
             column(width = 3, numericInput(ns('gamma_scale'), 'Scale', value = '1')))
  )
}


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  sidebarPanel(

    actionButton("add_btn", "Add Textbox"),
    actionButton("rm_btn", "Remove Textbox"),
    textOutput("counter")

  ),

  mainPanel(column(width = 12, id = "column"))

))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # Track the number of input boxes to render
  counter <- reactiveValues(n = 0)

  # Track all user inputs
  AllInputs <- reactive({
    x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
  })

  observeEvent(input$add_btn, {
    counter$n <- counter$n + 1
    insertUI(selector = "#column",
             where = "beforeEnd",
             ui = add_box(counter$n)
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$rm_btn, {
    if (counter$n > 0) {
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#new_box", counter$n))
      counter$n <- counter$n - 1
    }
  })

  output$counter <- renderPrint(print(counter$n))


})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thanks, i must read into modules. The output at the moment isn't correct though as when you click "add textbox", both gamma and normal available even though only "normal" is chosen?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice this feature in your example. I will try to adapt my answer

Comment: @user63230 it's corrected, I slightly changed the condition and added `ns = ns` in each `conditionalPanel`